# C# WPF app crashes with System.FormatException - Corrupt .resources file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resources, formatexception

I've inherited a C# .net WPF application from a now ex-employee and am having some difficulties running the application. It all builds fine without a single error or warning, but before the GUI appears I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Corrupt .resources file. Name position for index '156' is outside of name section '0xab02'.

Any suggestions on how to identify which .resources file it is and/or how to re-create them (I've tried rubuilding all which made no difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it turned out that although Visual Studio was set up to use v3.5 of the .net framework you need to seperately install v3.5 of the framework - it seems I only had v2 installed. Let this be a lesson for anyone else struggling with the same problems!